# sqflite query() won't work: "type 'QueryRow' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, String>' "

Tags: database, sqlite, flutter, dart, sqflite

I have two tables: 'notes' and 'groups'.Querying from groups works fine, as do all other requests, but from notes it does not.

I have the following: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RMipR.png)
I do not understand what is the problem, code for getting the tables is the same, only names and formating to and from Json.
I hope it is not some obvious mistake that I just can not see.

My code is as follows:

```
  import 'package:sqflite/sqflite.dart';
import 'package:sqflite/sqlite_api.dart';
import 'package:path/path.dart';

    import '../models/databaseException.dart' as de;
    import '../models/note.dart';
    import '../models/group.dart';

    class DBProvider {
      DBProvider._();
      static final DBProvider db = DBProvider._();
      static Database _database;

      Future<Database> get database async {
        if (_database != null) return _database;

        _database = await initDatabase();
        return _database;
      }

      initDatabase() async {
       await deleteDatabase(join(await getDatabasesPath(), 'faks_projekt.db'));
        return await openDatabase(
          join(await getDatabasesPath(), 'faks_projekt.db'), //Path for db
          onCreate: (db, version) async {
            await db.execute('''  
              CREATE TABLE notes(
                id TEXT PRIMARY KEY,
                n INTEGER,
                title TEXT,
                date TEXT,
                groupId TEXT,
                text TEXT
              )
            ''');

            await db.execute('''  
              CREATE TABLE groups(
                id TEXT PRIMARY KEY,
                title TEXT,
                r INT,
                g INT,
                b INT
              )
            ''');
          },
          version: 1,
        );

      }

      Future<Group> getGroupById(String id) async {
        try {
          final db = await database;
          final res = await db.query('groups', where: 'id=?', whereArgs: [id]);
          return res.isNotEmpty ? Group.fromJson(res.first) : null;
        } catch (error) {
          throw new de.DatabaseException('Error while GETTING GROUP BY ID.');
        }
      }

      Future<List<Group>> getAllGroups() async {
        try {
          var db = await database;
          final res = await db.query('groups');
          return res.isNotEmpty ? res.map((e) => Group.fromJson(e)).toList() : null;
        } catch (error) {
          throw new de.DatabaseException('Error while GETTING ALL GROUPS.');
        }
      }

      Future<Note> getNoteById(String id) async {
        try {
          final db = await database;
          final res = await db.query('notes', where: 'id=?', whereArgs: [id]);
          return res.isNotEmpty ? Note.fromJson(res.first) : null;
        } catch (error) {
          print(error.toString());
          throw new de.DatabaseException('Error while GETTING NOTE BY ID.');
        }
      }

      Future<List<Note>> loadNotes() async {
        try {
          final db = await database;
          final res = await db.query('notes');
          return res.isNotEmpty ? res.map((e) => Note.fromJson(e)).toList() : null;
        } catch (error) {
           print(error.toString());
          throw new de.DatabaseException('Error while GETTING  ALL NOTES.');
        }
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution, wrong data type when I was converting from json.